# Is there a subspace of $M^R_{2x3}$ that is isomorphic to $R_4[x]$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> Is there a subspace of $M^R_{2x3}$ that is isomorphic to $R_4[x]$?

For example, Can I say that $M^R_{2x2}$ is a subspace of $M^R_{2x3}$ so it can be isomorphic to $R_4[x]$ ? (because they have same dimensions maybe? and because they both can be "converted" to $R^4$? If I'm wrong please correct me)

Comment: What is $R_4[x]$? My usual guess would be something $5$-dimensional.

Comment: Nope. 4 dimensional. $R_4[x]$ its a polynom

Comment: See @Brian's response.

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming that 
$$\Bbb R_4[x]=\{f\in\Bbb R[x]:\deg f\leq 4\}$$
Note that $\{1,x,x^2,x^3,x^4\}$ is a basis for $\Bbb R_4[x]$ so $\dim\Bbb R_4[x]=5$. A basic theorem in linear algebra asserts that two finite-dimensional spaces are isomorphic if and only if they have the same dimension. Can you prove this theorem and find a five-dimensional subspace of $M_{2\times 3}(\Bbb R)$?

Hint: The subspace of $M_{2\times 3}(\Bbb R)$ spanned by
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 
\end{bmatrix},
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 
\end{bmatrix},
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 
\end{bmatrix}
$$
has dimension three.

Comment: No idea how to find a subspace maxtrix that will give me 5 dimension. Maybe $@M_{1x5}$

Comment: And about proving the theorm. I have the proof in the book.